# VBA root finder algorithm

Tags: vba, mathematics

I did two simple functions in VBA (see below).

When a user calls `TirNoPer360` in Excel he must select cashflows and dates (as range), then he will get a rate (through iterations according to the second function `TirNoPer360`).

```
Function Opt(Caja, Fecha As Range, tasa As Double)

Dim i As Integer
Dim sum As Double
Dim Initial As Date

Initial = Fecha(1, 1)

For i = 1 To Caja.Rows.Count
    sum = sum + Caja(i) / ((1 + tasa) ^ (Application.WorksheetFunction.Days360(Initial, Fecha(i)) / 360))
Next i

Opt = sum

End Function
```

======================

```
Function TirNoPer360(Cash, Dates As Range, rate As Double)
Dim tolerance  As Double
tolerance = 0.00001

For Iteration = 1 To 100
    If Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) > 0 And Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) > tolerance Then
        rate = rate + 0.0000001
    ElseIf Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) < 0 And Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) < tolerance * -1 Then
        rate = rate - 0.0000001            
    Else
        rate = rate
    End If
    TirNoPer360 = rate
Next Iteration

End Function
```

When cashflows and dates increase I need more than 100 tries in order to get a good rate (approximated to four decimals) and time increases a lot. So, I would like to speed up my code. 
I think I must improve the root finder algorithm, but I don't know how exactly I can do it.
Can anyone help me?

PD: I read Excel uses [Newton's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/algorithm-of-xirr-funcation) algorithm to find the root for a function.

Comment: What is a "good rate"?

Comment: One quick comment for speed-up is that you're calling the `Opt` function four times with the exact same parameters when you should only call it once. Set up a variable `Dim sum As Double; sum = Opt(Cash, Dates, rate)`, then use that result in the `If` statement:  `If sum > 0 And sum > tolerance Then...`. Additionally, we could help a bit more if you can supply a table of test data to run against so we know what to look for.

Comment: Just to point out that I improved optimization (root finder) through bisection method.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Function TirNoPer360(Cash, Dates As Range, rate As Double)
> ```

The function is implicitly `Public`, implicitly returns a `Variant`, and implicitly receives all its parameters `ByRef`; `Cash` is implicitly a `Variant`, and the name isn't making it obvious that...

> ```
> If Opt(Cash, Dates, rate)
> ```

...

> ```
> Function Opt(Caja, Fecha As Range, tasa As Double)
>     '...
>     For i = 1 To Caja.Rows.Count
> ```

...that `Cash` (and `Caja`) really needs to be a `Range` object, otherwise things can go all kinds of wrong.

Make these things explicit, pass parameters `ByVal`, and keep the same identifiers when concepts are the same:

```
Public Function TirNoPer360(ByVl Cash As Range, ByVal Dates As Range, ByVal rate As Double) As Double
```

```
Private Function Opt(ByVal Cash As Range, ByVal Dates As Range, ByVal rate As Double) As Double
```

Now it's much clearer that...

- `TirNoPer360` is the public UDF, and `Opt` is a private implementation detail of it.
- `Cash` in `TirNoPer360` is the same thing as what you had as `Caja` in `Opt`.
- The function(s) return a `Double`

This block needs immediate attention:

```
If Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) > 0 And Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) > tolerance Then
    rate = rate + 0.0000001
ElseIf Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) < 0 And Opt(Cash, Dates, rate) < tolerance * -1 Then
    rate = rate - 0.0000001            
Else
    rate = rate
End If
```

The entire `Else` block is no-op and should be removed. `rate` is already equal to `rate`, but the biggest inefficiency here is the fact that, in the worst case, `Opt` is invoked 4 times, and it's a very expensive function call. Pull it into a local variable ([as was already suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223958/23788)) and call it *once*:

```
Dim optResult As Double
optResult = Opt(Cash, Dates, rate)
```

And now the conditionals become:

```
If optResult > 0 And optResult > tolerance Then
    rate = rate + 0.0000001
ElseIf optResult < 0 And optResult < tolerance * -1 Then
    rate = rate - 0.0000001            
End If
```

The `tolerance` looks like it should be an optional parameter, with a default value of `0.00001`. You could amend the function's signature like this:

```
Public Function TirNoPer360(ByVl Cash As Range, ByVal Dates As Range, ByVal rate As Double, Optional ByVal tolerance As Double = 0.00001) As Double
```

Variable `Iteration` is not declared. I like that it's a fully spelled-out identifier and not just `i`, but given the variable has no use other than counting the number of iterations... so `i` wouldn't hurt at all. Just *declare it* - the fact that the code is allowed to run without this variable being declared indicates that `Option Explicit` is not specified at the top of the module, and that's a very dangerous thing, because any typo will merrily compile and run.. and produce the wrong results... and typos can be hard to spot. Spare yourself the trouble, and *always* put `Option Explicit` at the top of *every* module you ever write any code in.

> *I need more than 100 tries in order to get a good rate*

Your function needs to define a concept of what a "good rate" is, and bail out (`Exit Function`, or `Exit For`) when it gets one. Currently, the function performs 100 iterations every time, regardless of whether the 2nd or 99th iteration yielded a "good rate".

> ```
>     TirNoPer360 = rate
> Next Iteration
> ```

You're re-assigning the function's return value at every iteration. That's a redundant step, just assign it once, after the loop:

```
Next Iteration
TirNoPer360 = rate
```

Now, about that `Opt` function...

> ```
> For i = 1 To Caja.Rows.Count
>     sum = sum + Caja(i) / ((1 + tasa) ^ (Application.WorksheetFunction.Days360(Initial, Fecha(i)) / 360))
> Next i
> ```

`i` should be declared as a `Long`, not an `Integer`. I don't know how many rows this function is iterating, but `Caja` being a `Range` means it's absolutely possible that there are more than 32,767 (the maximum value an `Integer` can take).

The function would be more efficient if you were iterating a single-dimensional `Variant` array rather than a `Range`.

Consider declaring `Caja` and `Fecha` parameters `ByVal...As Variant`, and passing them from `TirNo360` like so:

```
Public Function TirNoPer360(ByVl Cash As Range, ByVal Dates As Range, ByVal rate As Double, Optional ByVal tolerance As Double = 0.00001) As Double

    Dim cashValues As Variant
    cashValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Cash.Value)

    Dim dateValues As Variant
    dateValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dates.Value)

    Dim optResult As Double
    optResult = Opt(cashValues, dateValues, rate)
```

Now instead of this:

> ```
> For i = 1 To Caja.Rows.Count
>     sum = sum + Caja(i) / ((1 + tasa) ^ (Application.WorksheetFunction.Days360(Initial, Fecha(i)) / 360))
> Next i
> ```

You'll have this (assuming the `Caja` parameter is now named `cashValues`):

```
Dim firstDate As Date
firstDate = dateValues(1)

For i = LBound(cashValues) To UBound(cashValues)
    sum = sum + cashValues(i) / ((1 + rate) ^ (Application.WorksheetFunction.Days360(firstDate, dateValues(i)) / 360))
Next
```

Now the only thing left to address, is the function names: I've no idea what `TirNoPer360` actually stands for, and `Opt` is very cryptic. Give your functions meaningful names that ideally start with a verb, like, `FindOptimalRate` or something.

Comment: thank very much for the feedbacks. I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

I want to understand this because it seems like an interesting problem, but it's difficult because the parameters are in Spanish and I don't really understand the business domain.

Some things to consider: are you sure there isn't a plugin somewhere that does this calculation?

If not, avoid repeat calculations. Instead of calling Opt four times, store it once to a variable and use that instead.

Also, try to think of a way you can store previous results in general. Do users keep calculating the same things over and over again? Could you store that in a table instead?

Could you maybe attach a spreadsheet with sample data that does the calculation?